# MySQL: Occasional SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server from PDO PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a MySQL database and a PHP script using PDO to connect to it.

The MySQL database is running on the same server as the PHP script.

Here's the code I use to connect:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $db_info[0]['hostname'] . ';dbname=' . $db_info[0]['db'], $db_info[0]['username'], $db_info[0]['password'], array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true ));
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);
```

My script is multi-threaded and opens multiple simultaneous connections.

What I'm seeing is that after running for about 30 seconds, the script will die and return a `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server` error, but the MySQL server is running and hasn't restarted or anything:

```
mysql> show status like "%uptime%";
+---------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name             | Value   |
+---------------------------+---------+
| Uptime                    | 1033900 |
| Uptime_since_flush_status | 1033900 |
+---------------------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm confused because my script works fine for a brief period of time, until (seemingly) randomly one of the threads will fail to obtain a connection to the server, and return that error and blow up.

Where should I look to debug why I would be receiving that error when connecting to a running local MySQL server?

I do see this which looks a little worrying:

```
mysql> show status like "%connections%";
+-----------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                     | Value |
+-----------------------------------+-------+
| Connection_errors_max_connections | 0     |
| Connections                       | 1197  |
| Max_used_connections              | 45    |
+-----------------------------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Could that be causing the issue?

Comment: Strangely, changing the server IP PDO is connecting to from an IP to a hostname made the error disappear.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. With me it seems the issue was the large number of concurrent connections. Any idea what I could try to resolve?